# Filtering and Calcultions with in Filtered Data

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the Program I have written to, Filter Inventory for a Date and to do a basic calculation only for the filtered Data. But I am not getting the result. Instead it displays 0, that to only in the 2nd cell of column. Some one could correct it..? (See pic.)

```
Sub Filter_RPCALC()

'Calculation of Date Diff.
Range("N2").Formula = "=DAYS($A$590,D2)"
Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N585"), Type:=xlFillDefault

'Calculation of Rp
Dim Rp As Integer
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As Integer
Dim var3 As Integer
var1 = Range("M2:M585").Select
var2 = Range("02:0585").Select
var3 = Range("L2:L585").Select
Rp = var1 * var2 + var3
Range("P2:P585").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Rp

'Filter the coils for Deliver Date
ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$585").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Range("A590"))

End Sub
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here `var1 = Range("M2:M585").Select` ? this should have raised a run-time error

Comment: I took the values of Column M2 to M585 as var1. But I didnt get an error. My aim is to do the calculation as below, Column P  = Column M * Column O + Column L @ShaiRado

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like the code below:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = 585 ' using the value from your code , you could use a dynamic range here
Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Formula = "=M2*O2+L2"
```